# Why ist this PHP Tag visible?

Tags: php, wordpress, variables

Hi have the following variable:

```
<?php
$url1 = bloginfo();
?>
```

Why is the variable visible in the frontend of wordpress?

If I try a the variable without Wordpress-Tag:

```
<?php
$url1 = "test";
?>
```

is it not visible.

Thanks for your help.

Best regards

Martin

Comment: What does bloginfo() do?  My guess is it is a function that outputs text :)

Comment: Because a Wordpress tag probably already has what it needs to echo whatever is processed. Doing `$url1 = "test"; echo $url1;` will echo `test`

Comment: Yes, for a example I will output

    echo "Mein Name ist $url1";

Comment: Then you probably need to do `bloginfo("$url1")` or in single quotes `bloginfo('$url1')` @user3037763

Comment: OK thanks Fred, but when I do it:


Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO in /www/htdocs/***/***/wp-content/plugins/php-execution-plugin/includes/class.php_execution.php(273) : eval()’d code on line 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bloginfo()` is used to display a particular piece of info about the site, like in `bloginfo('name')` which displays the site name. To get the value and store it in a variable, use `get_bloginfo()`.

See https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo for more info.

Answer (score 1):

[bloginfo](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo) outputs its information instead of returning it.

Therefore no matter where it's called from the output will be sent to the browser.

In your first example, your outputting the result of `bloginfo` to the browser and returning void (nothing). The second, your assigning a value to `$url1` of "test" and nothing is output.